# How can I check if the keyword set is exist in a sentence?

Tags: php, algorithm

I tried to check if the keyword is exist in some sentence.
If the keyword is just one, it is easy to find out whether match or not.
But if the big keyword set is given, it takes too much time to find out. So I searched out Aho-Corasick algorithm that takes linear time to find out.
But the algorithm was not helpful. Because it takes more time than using `strpos` function.
I thought that the keyword set is too big.

This is using navite php function.

```
$sentence = "The big brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
$keywords = array(...); // $keywords count is about 1,000,000
$keywordsCount = count($keywords);
$isMatched = false;
for ($i = 0; $i < $keywordsCount; $i++) {
    if (strpos($sentence, $keywords[$i])) {
        $isMatched = true;
    }
}
```

This is using aho-corasick algorithm. (https://github.com/MartyIX/AhoCorasickPHP/)

```
$sentence = "The big brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
$keywords = array(...); // $keywords count is about 1,000,000
$keywordsCount = count($keywords);
$isMatched = false;

$ac = new AhoCorasick();
$tree = $ac->buildTree($keywords);
$result = $ac->FindAll($sentence);
var_dump($result);
```

Using aho-corasick algorithm approach is about **3 times slower** than using `strpos` php function.
How can I check the keyword is matched in senctence more quickly and effectively?

Comment: Maybe you can do it the other way around. Instead of iterating over every element in the array, you can split the sentence and check if each word exists in the array of keywords. I think this will be faster if you have short sentences.

Comment: How long does it take with strpos()? How fast does it need to be? How volatile is the array of keywords?

Comment: Do you want to exit after the first match, count the number of matches, return the keywords contained in the sentence, or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By all accounts, including the official PHP manual, **`strpos()`** is by far the fastest method of finding a string within another.

Direct from the manual:

> If you only want to determine if a particular needle occurs within
>   haystack, use the faster and less memory intensive function strpos()
>   instead.

It's by far faster than `pregmatch()`, which is already very efficient memory-wise, and even faster than `strstr()`.

My point being that I seriously doubt that by any method you will find a function or craft an algorithm faster than the native `strpos()`.

Comment: That's not really his problem. His problem is that he needs a more efficient way of looking for a million different keywords inside a sentence.
The performance of his current algorithm is bad because he is searching in the string for every single keyword. A string searching algorithm is not efficient at all because it has to be able to find any substring (including spaces). Look at the answer below to get an idea of what could be a more efficient approach...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `$keywords` is a simple array...

```
$sentence = "The big brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
$words = explode(' ', strtolower($sentence));

$keywords = array(...); // $keywords count is about 1,000,000
$keywords_map = array_flip($keywords); // assuming all keywords are already lowercase

$isMatched = false;

foreach ($words as $word) {
    if (array_key_exists($word, $keywords_map)) {
        $isMatched = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Very smart, I like it. If the $keywords array actually has the keywords as its keys and not its values, you algorithm will be super fast (assuming PHP handles key/value arrays with a hash-table).